# Github actions- stop a check if the PR is merged or pushed to again

Tags: github-actions

We have tests that take about an hour to run. If I make a PR that just adds a comment somewhere, I don't want all of these tests to run and waste resources. If a PR is merged, is it possible for github actions to automatically cancel checks?

Also, if I create a PR and then push to that branch again, it runs a test for every push. Is there a way to cancel checks and restart when a commit is pushed to a branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like an "auto cancel builds", as it is called and available on other CI services, is not natively supported on GitHub Actions.

There are some non-native alternatives as discussed in this newer StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70452560/413924