# Cancel Action run, when Pull Request changes

Tags: github, github-actions

For my project, I have a pretty long github action that is triggered when a new pull request is created.
These are the triggers I use:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, ready_for_review, labeled]
```

This action is defined as a "status check" requirement for my pull request, to make sure that the action is running fine before allowing someone to merge his PR.

But, my PRs also require to be up to date with `develop` before being allowed to merge anything.

So the scenario I encounter frequently is this:

- Create a new Pull Request
- The Github Action starts, and my PR's check status go to "in progress"
- I realise that my branch is not up to date with develop, so I update it.
- The PR's check status go to "Expected", since my current run was started on a previous version of the branch.

My issue with that scenario, is that, even though my github action run is now completely invalid/obsolete (because the content of the branch changed), the action itself is still running. I need to manually go to the actions tab and cancel this run.

Is there a way to automatically cancel this run, if the content of the branch or the PR changed  ?

Answer (score 7):

As CI job ares executed in a different github runners, there is no direct way to automatically cancel previous CI jobs **natively** with Github Actions.

However, there as some workarounds to help you resolve your issue:

1 - use the Github API to [cancel workflow runs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#cancel-a-workflow-run) directly (which might not be trivial to automate in your specific case).

2 - use a [cancel-workflow-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/cancel-workflow-action), that will cancel any previous runs that are not `completed` for a given workflow.

3 - use a [skip-duplicate-actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/skip-duplicate-actions), to skip duplicate workflow-runs after merges, pull requests or similar.

4 - use the native [`concurrency` field](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency) to ensure that only a single job or workflow using the same concurrency group will run at a time.

Comment: Thank you for that. The concurrency field is very interesting as there is a `cancel-in-progress` option that I can play with.
However that's not 100% usable in my case, since I don't really know when the next action run will start (my first run is automatic, but subsequent runs are triggered manually on a Pull Request).
Still, these are some interesting leads, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across this exact issue and the solution was to create an action that listens for pushes on the target branch and then uses the API to cancel anything running that points the same branch.

```
name: Cancel out of date workflow runs
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  cancel-pr-workflows:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: octokit/request-action@v2.x
        id: get_active_workflows
        with:
          route: GET /repos/{repository}/actions/runs?status=in_progress&event=pull_request
          repository: ${{ github.repository }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Extract workflow ids
        id: extract_workflow_ids
        run: |
          current_branch=${GITHUB_REF##*/}

          # loop thru the workflows found & filter out ones that are not on PRs pointing to this branch
          # or do not match "Automated tests"
          workflow_ids=$(echo '${{ steps.get_active_workflows.outputs.data }}' | \
            jq '.workflow_runs | map({id, name, baseBranch: .pull_requests[0].base.ref})' | \
            jq 'map(select(.name == "Automated tests" and .baseBranch == "'$current_branch'")) | map(.id)' | \
            jq 'join(",")')

          # strip the wrapping quote marks before passing to next step
          echo 'WORKFLOW_IDS='$(echo $workflow_ids | tr -d '"') >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Cancel active workflows
        run: |
          for i in ${WORKFLOW_IDS//,/ }
          do
            echo "Cancelling workflow with id: $i"

            # use curl here as I have no idea how to use a github action in a loop
            curl \
              -X POST \
              -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
              -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
              https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/$i/cancel
          done
```